# SQL Joining tables; can you repeat columns?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, join

I'm trying to compose a view that we can use to export our inventory.

I have two tables:

**Inventory**, which contains the columns Description, Year, Make, Model, and Serial.

**Pictures**, which contains the columns DocumentBody, MimeType, Serial, and Last Modified.

I'd like to make a view that has all columns from Inventory, and also adds columns for x amount of Pictures related to Serial number.

So if there were two pictures with the same serial number, the resultant table would include these fields:

Description, Year, Make, Model, Serial, DocumentBody1, MimeType1, Last Modified1, DocumentBody2, MimeType2, Last Modified2.

For those Inventory items that only have one picture, the second picture columns would all be null.

Is this something I can even do?  From what I'm reading about joins, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: If you don't know the number of `Pictures` per `Inventory` record ahead of time, you should likely rethink your design.  Tables are meant to have `n` rows, not columns.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to do this?

Comment: There is a maximum of ten pictures per inventory item. There may be only one picture or zero pictures uploaded however. So I do know the limits.

Comment: I need to be able to do this because I'm trying to export all the images to be uploaded to another website. The plan was that if I could get the view correct, I could then extract each DocumentBody save it as the appropriate file based on MimeType, and then replace DocumentBody with a URL to the newly created file. That was my hope anyway.... SQL is seriously way over my head.

Comment: `There is a maximum of ten pictures per inventory item` - these kinds of rules tend to change over time, might as well design for n pictures and let a business rule at software level enforce that... if enforcing it is ever necessary. Dont't design with only today's considerations, it might bite you in the #$$ later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you should probably evaluate whether you actually need the view you think you need. But if you really want it, you could use PIVOT in MSSQL:

```
WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT Serial
        ,DocumentBody
        ,MimeType
        ,LastModified
        ,ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY LastModified) AS RowNum
    FROM Pictures) AS t
),
DocumentPivot AS (
    SELECT 
        Serial
        ,DocumentBody
        ,'DocumentBody' + RowNum AS ColumnName
    FROM BaseData
),
MimePivot AS (
    SELECT 
        Serial
        ,MimeType
        ,'MimeType' + RowNum AS ColumnName
    FROM BaseData
),
ModifiedPivot AS (
    SELECT 
        Serial
        ,LastModified
        ,'LastModified' + RowNum AS ColumnName
    FROM BaseData
)
SELECT Description
    ,Year
    ,Make
    ,Model
    ,Inventory.Serial
    ,DocumentBody1
    ,MimeType1
    ,LastModified1
    ,DocumentBody2
    ,MimeType2
    ,LastModified2
    ,...
    ,LastModified10
FROM Inventory
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT Serial
            ,DocumentBody1
            ,DocumentBody2
            ,...
            ,DocumentBody10
        FROM DocumentPivot
            PIVOT (MAX(DocumentBody) FOR ColumnName IN (DocumentBody1, DocumentBody2, ..., DocumentBody10)) AS P1
    ) AS Documents
        ON Documents.Serial=Inventory.Serial
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT Serial
            ,MimeType1
            ,MimeType2
            ,...
            ,MimeType10
        FROM MimePivot
            PIVOT (MAX(MimeType) FOR ColumnName IN (MimeType1, MimeType2, ..., MimeType10)) AS P2
    ) AS Mimes
        ON Mimes.Serial=Inventory.Serial
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT Serial
            ,LastModified1
            ,LastModified2
            ,...
            ,LastModified10
        FROM ModifiedPivot
            PIVOT (MAX(LastModified) FOR ColumnName IN (LastModified1, LastModified2, ..., LastModified10)) AS P3
    ) AS Modifieds
        ON Modifieds.Serial=Inventory.Serial
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic response! This will produce a view that has all picture data in columns for each truck. The only problem with this is that it generates all that data every time. I'm thinking the best way to do this is to have a job that runs with the main info export, that just exports the pictures - and only if the Last Modified date has changed. that would reduce the amount of work it has to re-do every export, and the files would just be sitting there with a URL to them built into the main export Picture1, Picture2, ...Picture10 columns. I've got more work to do but Joosh, you are an angel!

Answer (score 2):

`Select inventory.*, count(pictures.serial) as picture_count From inventory Left Join pictures On inventory.serial = pictures.serial Where [your where statement]`

Use `Left Join` in case there are no pictures at all.  This way you still get back a result.

**Update**

Actually, after reading your question again, it seems you just want to extend your search results with each additional picture in the system.  That's not the best way to do this.  The best you can do is just get a row returned for each pic that's in the system.

`Select inventory.*, pictures.DocumentBody, pictures.MimeType, pictures.Serial, pictures.Last_Modified From inventory Left Join pictures On inventory.serial = pictures.serial Where [your where statement]`

Since there is no "Group By" clause, this will give you 1 row for each picture.  Then you can just loop through the results.

**Also**

There are ways to do this by making temp tables, looping through results within a stored procedure, creating new columns (DocumentBody1, DocumentBody2, etc) for each picture result and adding the data to the new fields, then querying the temp table.  But that's a lot to go through I would think.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help everyone. In the end, I ended up using PHP to accomplish this with the following code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');

$serverName = "database";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CRM_MSCRM");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Unable to connect.\n\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
else
    {
        echo "Connected. Selecting trucks...\n\n";
    }

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.Trader_Export_Simple";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false )
    {
        echo "Error executing query.\n\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

$csvData = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
        $count = 1;
        $mainpicsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.TruckImages WHERE Serial = '".$row[0]."' AND MainPic = 1";
        $mainpicstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $mainpicsql);
        while ($mainpicrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mainpicstmt))
            {
                $truck = $mainpicrow[1];
                $mainfilename = $truck ."-". $count . ".png";
                file_put_contents($mainfilename, base64_decode($mainpicrow[0]));
                $mainpicdate = $mainpicrow[3]->format("d/m/Y h:m:s");
                $mainfilename = "http://images.website/images/".$mainfilename;
                echo $mainpicdate."\n";
            }

        $picsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.TruckImages WHERE Serial = '".$row[0]."' AND MainPic = 0";
        $picstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $picsql);
        $extrapicsdate = "";
        $filenames = "";

        while ($picrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($picstmt))
            {
                $count++;
                $filename = $picrow[1] ."-". $count . ".png";
                file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($picrow[0]));
                $picdate = $picrow[3]->format("d/m/Y h:m:s");
                $filenames .= "http://images.website/images/".$filename.";";
                $extrapicsdate .= $picdate.";";
            }

        $filenames = rtrim($filenames, ";");
        $extrapicsdate = rtrim($extrapicsdate, ";");
        echo $filenames."\n";
        echo $extrapicsdate."\n";
        if ($truck != "") {
            $csvData[] = array($truck, $mainfilename, $mainpicdate, $filenames, $extrapicsdate);
        }

        if ($filenames != "")
            {
                $filenames = "";
            }        
        if ($extrapicsdate != "")
            {
                $extrapicsdate = "";
            }

        echo "Next truck...\n\n";
        $truck = "";
        $mainfilename = "";
        $mainpicdate = "";
    }
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($csvData as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    //print_r($csvData);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $picstmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

this gets the files out but I still have to merge the resultant CSV with the main "information" CSV.